# Javascript word count price calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery

Everything works fine, except the problem with a pricing plan selection. What I want is that whenever user clicks on a specified price (even while the text is already present in textarea), it should immediately update the final Price. But it won't change at first click.

I should click twice on it instead. Any one got an idea what's wrong ?

So here how it looks like:

[image]

And here comes the javascript code:

```
function __textCalculatorCounter(){

    var value = $('#calculateText').val();
    var spanWords = $('#calculatedWordsTotal'),
        spanChars = $('#calculatedCharsTotal'),
        spanPrice = $('#calculatedPriceTotal');


    if (value.length == 0) {
        spanWords.html(0);
        spanChars.html(0);
        return;
    }

    var selectedPricing = $("input[name=calculatePrice]:checked").val();
    var wordCount = value.trim().replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length;
    var totalChars = value.length;
    var totalPrice = (wordCount * parseFloat(Math.round(selectedPricing * 100) / 100));

    spanWords.html(wordCount);
    spanChars.html(totalChars);
    spanPrice.html(totalPrice.toFixed(2));
}

function _initTextCalculator(){
    var textblock = $('#calculateText');
    textblock.change(__textCalculatorCounter);
    textblock.keydown(__textCalculatorCounter);
    textblock.keypress(__textCalculatorCounter);
    textblock.keyup(__textCalculatorCounter);
    textblock.blur(__textCalculatorCounter);
    textblock.focus(__textCalculatorCounter);
    $('label', '#pricesGroup').click(__textCalculatorCounter);
}
```

**==== UPDATED ====**

I don't know why, but it works fine in jsfiddle... it's exactly the same code extracted from html and javascript.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/L8u87nno/)

Comment: mind providing a complete test case with code?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - will do in a moment

Comment: Notice also that `$('label', '#pricesGroup')` will not trigger anything since it's a wrong selector and will not attach any action event to it.

Comment: If it works in JSFiddle then there is something else interfering in your web

Comment: @pablito.aven - Could it be because of Twitter Bootstrap radio buttons ? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio Maybe there is a delay before before applying a "checked" attribute into the styled radio button ? I'm really noob in coding, so sorry for stupid questions if any

Comment: There is a difference tho from this post to your jsfiddle. Your function `_initTextCalculator` is fired inside document ready. Here, in your question's code, it is only being defined

Comment: @pablito.aven, good catch. When an OP insists "it's exactly the same code", it means it's probably not the same code. :)

Comment: @pablito.aven - really, it's the same. and it works when I switch to native radio buttons and not those bootstrap styled ones. I think there is some delay between styling and updating the radio button, which is already late, because the value is already processed (which is the old value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since no one had an answer, I post mine, which solved the issue.

The problem is in Twitter's Bootstrap 3 radio button styles which is actually common issue when using along with javascript.

I've changed a click handler for radio buttons:

```
function _initTextCalculator(){
    var textblock = $('#calculateText');
    textblock.change(_textCalculatorTrigger);
    textblock.keydown(_textCalculatorTrigger);
    textblock.keypress(_textCalculatorTrigger);
    textblock.keyup(_textCalculatorTrigger);
    textblock.blur(_textCalculatorTrigger);
    textblock.focus(_textCalculatorTrigger);

    // Fixing bootstrap 3 radio buttons
    $("#pricesGroup label").on('click', function(){
        // Once clicked, mark current radio as checked
        $('input:radio', this).prop("checked", true);
        // Then call a function to calculate the price
        _textCalculatorTrigger();
    });
}
```

As it already commented, it assigns a property "checked" to radio button first once it's parent `label` tag is clicked, and then it calls a function to calculate the price.

Thanks to everyone